# Origin of the word "duh"

Tags: etymology, writing, interjections

What is the origin of the word ["duh"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duh) as in the interjection:

> — It's hot in the desert.
>   — Well, duh!

If it is of onomatopoeic origin and only appears in modern English as some sites suggest, I would be interested to know when it started appearing in English writing.

Comment: I remember seeing speech bubbles for Moose a few decades ago from Archie Comics that often began with "Duh!"

Comment: The reason Moose said it so often is that he is a "low intelligence" character.  I don't remember ever reading it from the Jughead though, and it's not a normal part of his character (that doesn't mean his character never used that word though).

Comment: @Randolf - I have to post a correction for the sake of the internet. My eyes were playing a trick on me and the place where I thought it mentioned Jughead was actually a second reference to Moose. I have removed the comment above.

Comment: No worries!  I think your comment was fine, actually (and I encourage you to undelete it if you can).

Comment: For what it's worth, it sounds like "да" in Russian, which means "yes"

Comment: Just a personal note: As a child, I remember using duh for the exact reasons stated above. I feel sure I was using it when I was in the 10 to 13 year old range and I am 76 now, so that puts it in the 1947 to 1950 range for me. Of course it likely started before that.

Comment: This first I remember hearing (reading) "Duh" was as used by a comic strip character named Denny who was depicted as a low intelligence child.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Merriam Webster, *duh* is an interjection which has two [meanings](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duh):

> 1. used to express actual or feigned ignorance or stupidity
> 2. used derisively to indicate that something just stated is all too obvious or self-evident

Apparently this first appeared in 1966 (per Merriam Webster). If you look at Google NGrams, "duh" has appeared even in the 1800s but a quick look at the results shows that in the early cases "duh" was used mostly as a syllable in a foreign language or as a form of "the". You can see that there is an increase over time, regardless, after 1960.

[image]

The etymology of the interjection is, as you suggested, onomatopoeic in origin. One site, Think-Ink, devotes an entire [page](http://www.think-ink.net/doh/meaning.htm) to the discussion of the word. One thing they mention is an etymology, from the American Heritage Dictionary:

> Imitative of the utterance attributed to slow-witted people.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in many places this is quoted as the first appearance which predates the 66 date by quite a few years: "1943 Merrie Melodies (animated cartoon) in J. E. Lighter Hist. Dict. Amer. Slang (1994) I. 672/1 Duh... Well, he can't outsmart me, 'cause I'm a moron."

Comment: Also the Archie character Moose has been around at least since 1949.

Comment: I wonder if *duh* as used to imitate slow-witted folk was just a variation of the hesitant *uh*, which can be used similarly?

Answer (score 3):

The OED's says it's origin is imitative and gives a first quotation from a 1943 Merrie Melodies cartoon (as documented in J. E. Lighter's *Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994)):

> Duh... Well, he can't outsmart me, 'cause I'm a moron.

Checking further, the cartoon is *Jack-Wabbit and the Beanstalk* starring Bugs Bunny, and the quote is from the giant. Here's some more dialogue from [IMDb](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0036052/quotes?qt=qt0542320):

> Bugs Bunny: [Nervously] Eh, what's up doc?
>   Giant: Duh, caught ya choppin' up my victory garden, huh?, Well don't try nuttin' funny cuz I got ya covered!
>    [Pulls out a gun]
>    Bugs Bunny: [to the Giant] Hey come here Gulliver!, I want to tell you something, come here!
>    [Giant leans over towards him]
>   Giant: [Bugs takes off his glove and slaps him with it] Duh, duh now why did you wanna go and
>   do that for huh?
>   Bugs Bunny: You want to fight fair don't you? That means that I challenge you to a duel!   Giant: Duh, duel? uh, oh yeah!, okay!

You can watch the cartoon on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaNbFTRWvGU).